# Prove or disprove if it is enumerable

Tags: logic

I'm doing some excercises from the book "The Incompleteness Phenomenom" from Goldstern and Judah and I have to prove or disprove this:

If $C$ is an inductive structure with a finite number of blocks and a finite number of operations, then the number of elements in C is enumerable. What happens if the number of blocks is enumerable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is you intuition? is this true or not? what did you try?

Comment: I think that the first question is true and the second false, but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: It is countable in both cases: consider the second case as a countable union of structures of the first case.

Comment: @Crostul Since this is about computability, I suspect enumerable means "recursively enumerable", and since there are countable sets that are not recursively enumerable, you need to do a bit more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution but hints that should help you finding the solution by yourself. If it does not please ask.

First case: finite number of block + finite number of operation: you are right $C$ is enumerable.
Hints to prove it:

What can you say about the number of element obtained with less than $n$ operations?

Can you use this to enumerate all the element of $C$?

> hint: if $e\in C$ then there exists $n$ such that $e$ is obtained by applying less than $n$ operations

Second case: enumerable set of blocks + finite rules: $C$ is still enumerable.
Hints to prove it:

Let the blocks be $\{B_1,B_2,\dots\}$.

What can you say about the number of elements obtain with less than $n$ operation **and** only with blocks form $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$?

Can you use this to enumerate all the element of $C$?

> Again if $E\in C$ then there exist $n$ such that $e$ is obtained with less than $n$ operation **and** only with blocks form $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$